# Daily, Weekly and Monthly Reports from Solarwinds?

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I'm working with a Solar Winds NPM/NTA/IPAM golden-trio. I'd like to customize our reports to the point where I can received daily, weekly or monthly emails for various things - 95th percentile errors, bandwidth utilization on ingress / egress (not netflow, from SNMP), up and downtime's, etc.

Unless I am completely missing it, where would I "click in" to create and then modify these functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They keep moving things into the web interface but the reports are in a separate app called "Report Writer" on the server desktop so you'll have to RDP or physically connect to the server to get to it. There's also a "Report Scheduler" where you'll need add the reports once you've created them.

I've never found their reporting very useful but you may have better luck depending on what you want. In the past I know they've recommended using Crystal Reports against their database to pull detailed reports.